# Nodejs express regex routing with variable in it - why does not match?

Tags: node.js, regex, express

I am using express 4.16 and I want to create a route that accepts every path with a variable at the end.

I tried something like this but it does not match :S

```
 ...
    router.get('/.*:name$/', (req, res) => {
    ...
```

for example:

```
.../animal/Joe
.../fruit/apple.txt
.../people/man/Sam
```

I used this page to test it:
http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/

Edit 1 -----------------
So as I mentioned I am trying to create an svg api that gives back a public svg file in a different color. Example: localhost:3000/svg/logo/logo.svg?color=#232323

server.js:

```
..
const svg = require('./server/routes/svg');
...
app.use('/svg', svg);
...
```

svg.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router  = express.Router();
var   fs      = require('fs');

router.get('/.*:name$/', (req, res) => {
    let name  = req.params.name;
    let color = req.query.color;
    console.log(req.path, color, req.originalUrl, req.path);
    if(typeof name != 'undefined' && typeof color != 'undefined'){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/svg+xml');
        //                  here I should concatenate req.path before name or something like this idk..
        let read = fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/../../dist/assets/images/svg/${name}.svg`, 'utf8', (err, template) => {
            if(typeof template !== 'undefined'){
                let svg = template.replace(/\#000000/g, (match) => {
                    return color;
                });
                return res.send(svg);
            }else{
                return res.status(404).send();
            }
        });
    }else{
        return res.status(404).send();
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

(This code is not compleate I just stuck with the router)

Thanks your time in advance! :)

Comment: It's not clear from your question what precisely you're trying to match and what params you're expecting to capture.

Comment: I want to create an api that gives back svg files based on path like localhost:3000/svg/pathWhereICanFindThisFile/icon.svg?color=#232323 so I can read the svg modify its color and return it as a response. I just wanted to minify my question :)

Comment: That's super dangerous, if you're going to let random web users traverse your directories like that.

Comment: Could you explain why? If there is no svg name at the end of the path or color parameter I return an empty svg. On the other hand with correct path, filename and valid color I return a public file with a different color. I dont think it could be dangerous

Comment: However I guess this page do something very similar with his downloadable svgs https://www.flaticon.com/ (not sure)

Comment: well, put another way, why would you expect your clients to know that information?

Comment: It is not necessary for them to know this api. I want to use it on front-end where I can colorize my page from css. This way I can manipulate color of every svg file without exponential storage place. Other way I should save every svg file with the 255^3 color as different name. I would avoid that :S

Comment: The color param is a simpler thing, that's just the querystring.  I'm talking about the arbitrarily-lengthed directory to the svg file.

Comment: You're probably not matching anything because you have a `$` end of input special character followed by another character, which is impossible.

Comment: I cant get it. I used regex in several languages but this router is something strange... it does not match .* or /.* or (.*) or /(.*) I have tried every simple regex to match but still :s

Comment: @BálintRéthy for the version 0.1.7 of path-to-regexp, the character `*` is compiled to `(.*)`, and the `.` character is escaped to `\.` that's probably the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing with [Express Route Tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/) I came up with this pattern:

```
*/:name
```

According to the Route Tester, this pattern will be compiled (valid for path-to-regexp 0.1.7) into the following regular expression:

```
/^(.*)\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$/i
```

`^(.*)` will capture everything from the start

`([^\/]+?)` will capture and store the last value into `name`

**Note:** Is important to observe that `*` is compiled to `(.*)`.

For the latest version of path-to-regexp the following pattern should be equivalent:

```
(.*)/:name
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: My hero! Thank you very much and for the time of the others :)

Answer (score 0):

Against my better judgement, you can do what you're looking for with a regex that is not named.

```
router.get('/svg/path/(.*)', (req, res) => {
  // in here, you'll get the full path with req.path and then parse it validate it's the right form and to get the info you need out of it.

  // You can also use req.query to get the color param you mentioned.  
});
```

Comment: This router hates me. Still not matches :(